# Retrieve duplicates and show them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have this problem where I want to output rows that have the same name in another row. If the row does not have an another row with the same name, do not retrieve that row.

|id|name|
|1|battlefield review|
|2|call of duty review|
|3|battlefield review|
|4|saints row review|
|5|call of duty review|
|6|Overwatch review|

The rows I want to retrieve are:

|id|name|
|1|battlefield review|
|3|battlefield review|
|2|call of duty review|
|5|call of duty review|

This is what I got so far

```
@unique_ids = ExternalReview.select("DISTINCT ON (name) id").map(&:id)
@external_reviews = ExternalReview.where.not(id: @unique_ids).order("name ASC").paginate per_page: 25, page: params[:page]
```

I hope you can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id, 
       NAME 
FROM   table1 
WHERE  NAME IN (SELECT NAME 
        FROM   table1 
        GROUP  BY NAME 
        HAVING Count (DISTINCT NAME) > 1)
```

Try self join as above

Comment: Answered above as you have the question tagged as postresql.